# How to find the average of EACH samples out of a 100 samples I took from a large data set

Tags: r

First question. For example if my data has x,y,z columns and I want to take a sample size of 200. How should I do it? What i tried was `sample(data,200)` which appears to be an error, what I can only do is `sample(data$x,200)`. Is there a way that I can have a sample size of 200 of all x, y, z at the same time instead of doing it three times with $x, $y, $z?

Another question I have is that I have a large data set and need to take 100 samples of size 200. What i did was `replicate(100, sample(data$x, 200))`. How do I find the mean of EACH separate samples?

Thank you guys, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: columns are usually related; rows are more commonly sampled.

Comment: second question.  you have result<-replicate(100, sample(data$x, 200)) then sapply(result, mean) to get the means of each sample

Comment: probably would be good to clarify for everybody with a small example what exactly you want with question 1

Comment: I am sorry for not stating the question clearly. There are types, color, prices  types can take on value 1,2,3 colors take on value 4,5,6 and prices ranges from 30000 to 70000. and there are over 40000 in the population.  My first question is how do I create a random sample of size 200. and then 1. find the proportion of type 1 and 2. average price.  My second question is I need to take 100 samples of size 200 and find the average and standard deviation of these 100 estimates... I am not sure if I am clear enough...sorry guys.. but I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
#Fake data
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = runif(1000), z = sample(1000))
#Create an index
idx <- sample(nrow(x), 200, replace = FALSE)
#calculate the column means
colMeans(x[idx, ])
#create a list of indices and make a list
idx2 <- replicate(100, sample(nrow(x), 200, replace = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)
#Iterate over the list, taking the column means...only show the top six rows
t(sapply(idx2, function(zz) colMeans(x[zz, ])))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! is there a way to find the columns standard deviation? is there something like "colSd" or function that works just like colMeans except for targeting the sd?

Comment: There might be a package that has a colSDs function (but not in base or stats) ,  so why not just `sapply(x, sd)`?

Comment: @Ekam - what BondedDust outlined is probably your best approach, i.e. this: `sapply(x[idx, ], sd)`, or combine them together with something like this: `sapply(x[idx, ], function(zz) c(mean = mean(zz), sd = sd(zz)))`

Comment: @Chase   Thank you for much for the clear explanation! I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 sample(unlist(data), 200)
```

Comment: This will not work if the size of data < 200...

Comment: this also loses the original structure of the data, essentially turning it into a big vector...which is different than what the OP asked for I think

Comment: yeah I know it would lose structure, but I guess I mis read question. Im not used to answering questions really, sorry. Id suggest sample(as.matrix(data), 200) then...

Comment: Perhaps `lapply( data, sample, size=200)`? Originally I put that in as sapply, but I wondered if the factor variables would get messed up.